# Confusion about using indexes

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, indexing

I am having a table with columns appid,logmessage and date. here, neither of the log message,date or appid are `unique` or `primary keys`.

I have confusion about usage of indexes. The table might have millions of rows, hence it is very much required that the data retieval should be as efficient as possible.

can any one suggest good design for this table using clusterd and non clustered indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You should place the index on the column used to filter the data.

In this case, it could be appid and date.

You must be able to predict or detect the SQL run against this table to decide which indexes are required.

if it mostly filter on appid and date, create one index including both columns.

Comment: can we use combination of clustered index and non clustered index?

Comment: Only one clustered index per table. Clustered indexes have a higher maintenance cost.